How to Iterate through one parameter with multiple values
I have the following yml file:
parameters:
- name: Schemes
  type: string
  default: 'Staging'
  values: ['QA', 'Staging']

- name: test
  displayName: Run Tests?
  type: boolean
  default: false

variables:
- name: variable1
  value: QA,Staging

trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
  - ${{ if eq(parameters.test, true) }}:
    # Loop Schemes parameter values..
    - ${{ each scheme in split(variables.variable1, ',')}}:
      - script: echo "Running tests.. ${{ scheme }}"

Current YML View:

What I would like to do?
I'd like to iterate through Schemes parameter values instead variable1 variable values.. How can I do it?

When working with string arrays, the parameter type should be object. First, update this is your definition.
To loop through the values in a string array parameter, you can target the parameter directly  by using parameters.Schemes.
Here's what your pipeline definition should look like:
parameters:
- name: Schemes
  type: object
  default: ['Staging']
  values: ['QA', 'Staging']

- name: test
  displayName: Run Tests?
  type: boolean
  default: false

trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
  - ${{ if eq(parameters.test, true) }}:
    # Loop Schemes parameter values..
    - ${{ each scheme in parameters.Schemes }}:
      - script: echo "Running tests.. ${{ scheme }}"


But this one creates like a textbox for Schemes parameter.. is there a way to keep the schemes view like the image I attached in my question? like a radio button group

You want to run tests for each environment regardless of which environment was selected, I'm guessing? It's not possible to reference the values property of a parameter programmatically, unfortunately; parameters.Schemes is the value passed to the pipeline, and it has no member properties. You would need to use DevOps extensions and implement custom controls for the object with CSS and Javascript to have a radio box group displayed.

oh.. Sad I can't loop the values of the parameter :( Thanks anyway.
